Как настроить прокси ssh_ss в Linux для Viber?
Как настроить прокси ssh_ss в Linux для Viber?
Что за тип прокси ssh_ss ?
Как настроить на Linux и какие утилиты нужны?
Что такое просто ssh знаю.

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

SSH_SS это похоже на shadowsocks сервер запущенный на ssh сервере.
Сделано так чтоб скрыть передачу пароля от shadowsocks.
Нужно настроить openssh сервер по типовому: AllowTcpForwarding там..
shadowsocks настраивается на 127.0.0.1 , а дальше зависит от того куда трафик будет форвардиться.
